# walkthrough adding library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and Android Programming and as I am just learning this by myself I have no one else to ask.

Can someone walk me through the steps in how to add a third party library dependency? I'm interested in using the infiniteviewpager https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

I see the instructions from the page but where do I enter the commands??? 
I've searched but there is just TMI.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but it literally tells you to "add the following to your build.gradle"... And that would be the build.gradle for the module, not the project where it says not to add dependencies

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is this the way to do it? [img]http://i.imgur.com/RTRI7J5.png[/img]   What does the note in the build.gradle mean.         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

Comment: That is not correct. That note means do not add it there, add it to the *other* build.gradle in the subfolder for your app

Comment: got it! Thanks! It's such a simple thing but it was beginning to frustrate me when I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: now that it is added. I'm running into errors when running it in my emulator. Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dependencies {
compile 'com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0'
  }
```

put these in build.gradle (Module:app) and synchronised the project

Comment: now that it is added. I'm running into errors when running it in my emulator. Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'. > Could not find com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0. – lemmi 1 hour ago

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line of code in `gradle.build` like shown in the picture

```
compile 'com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager:library:1.0.0'
```

[image]